# When will body has class "page-id-0"

Tags: pages

In my other project, I've been relying on checking body's class to find out what page the current webpage is using.
However on this page http://seminary.fbny.org/register/ the body has a class `page-id-0`, where does this come from? I don't believe page or post's ID could be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely plugin related in your case: BuddyPress seems to set the global post ID to 0 on its virtual pages, (see e.g. this [ticket](https://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6230)).